# Inline condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

```
  - if (typeof(person) == 'undefined')
    input(type="text", name="person[Name]")
  - else
    input(type="text", name="person[Name]", value="#{person.Name}")
```

Is there any way to write this inline? I have an option select and I don't want to do a conditional statement for 30+ values to select the right option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

conditional statement should do

```
input(type='text', name='person[Name]', value= (person?(person.name?person.name:''):''))
```

however, by design we can always pass a person? this way there is no comparison required. Code would be something like

```
input(type='text', name='person[Name]', value= person.name)
```

Comment: That is of course brilliant. Passing an empty object to prevent "undefined" errors, no need for mixing or conditionals. I used JavaScript to select the option in the list, as the conditional statement didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

You could use mixins

```
mixin safeInput(person, property)
  - if (typeof(person) == 'undefined')
    input(type="text", name="person[#{property}]")
  - else
    input(type="text", name="person[#{property}]", value="#{person[property]}")
```

Then

```
mixin safeInput(person, 'Name')
mixin safeInput(person, 'Email')
...
```

Comment: Hmm, not bad. I have to see if that works for option-select's as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can short circuit as follows:

```
input(type="text", name="person[Name]", value="#{person && person.Name}")
```

Answer (score -1):

When the value is `undefined` or `null`, the attribute will not be shown. This should work:

```
input(type='text', name='person[Name]', value= person && typeof(person))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Jade shows a 500 ReferenceError if person is not defined. If person is defined, it says "string" instead of the value in the input box. So that doesn't work.